How do i determine the fermi energy for a band structure?
I have calculated the band structure of Bi (Structure: Rhomohedral, Geometry: Trigonal). I am unable to figure out how to determine the lowest of conduction and highest of valence band for a corresponding k-point value. For this, as much as I know, I think I will need Fermi energy. Using that, I can have some idea about the lowest and highest bands. But then the question is, how do I obtain the Fermi energy? I have run the scf calculations (for smearing = Fermi-Dirac). I have also run the band structure calculations (for k-points G-T-L-F-Z) as well as the DOS calculations. Now what is the next part to obtain the Fermi energy.
I apologize for my little knowledge about this field, as this question might be stupid to some, but I am new to this field. So a little would be really appreciated.
I have also attached the graphs for reference.



You need to look in the output file. Normally, the Fermi energy is printed there. With that energy in hands, you “mark” it in the band graph and look for the band energies below/above it for a given k.

You tagged the quantum espresso to the question. Therefore, I think that you used from QE for DFT calculation. But, when you perform scf calculations in QE for metals with semaring option, in output file, you can easily find the fermi energy (for metals). If you don't use from smearing option but give enough khon sham states with nbnd, you can find the highest occupied and lowest unoccupied states from scf calculation output file (this is for insulator and semiconductors not metals).
If you use from other DFT codes, you have to mention it then we can help to find solution.
Jasurbek Gulomov

I did tag QE, but I used BURAI inter face to perform the calculations. Can you answer according to that. Apologies for the confusion

BURAI is not a DFT code. BURAI is just an interface for QE.

That's what I said, I used BURAI Interface.

Burai and Quantum Espresso are the same thing. Core of Burai is Quantum Espresso. So you can find the Fermi energy using above method even in Burai. You have to look at output file of scf calculation. All output files should be generated where project was created in Burai.
